# Is there a way to activate the abort sequence from the keyboard?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Version 0.18 introduced action groups, including a dedicated abort group.  This can be activated using the pop out button next to the altimeter, but I'm wondering if this can be done from the keyboard.  Instead of searching for the UI button while my rocket is exploding below me, I'd rather just hit a keyboard hotkey.  What is the hotkey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Kerbal Space Program wiki](http://kspwiki.nexisonline.net/wiki/Key_Bindings) says that the default key binding for executing the Emergency Abort is <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.